# Setting ComboBox.SelectedIndex Breaks OneWayToSource Binding On ComboBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, combobox

The following appears in a data template:

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumeratedValues, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

With `SelectedIndex` being set (as shown above), the `OneWayToSource` binding to `Value` does not work. If I do not set `SelectedIndex` the binding to `Value` is fine.

However, I'd really like to set `SelectedIndex` to 0 because if I omit setting it, *no* item is selected by default in the `ComboBox`.

Can anybody see a way that I can keep my binding to `Value` working while at the same time ensuring that the first item in the `ComboBox` is selected by default?

Comment: Dave, nothing is showing up between ...appears in a data template:  and  With SelectedIndex being set (as shown above)...
Is there some source code missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and if people wan't to say that it simply doesn't work that way then I'm shocked. Also what would be the purpose of SelectedIndex as all ComboBoxes must be bound to something (otherwise they would be useless).

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a two-way binding and just set the Value property of your object in code behind?

Edit: Added explanation: This allows you to just work with your business object.  The point of using data binding is to separate your business objects from the UI and just manipulate your business object and have the UI reflect that.

Comment: I actually considered this, but for SelectedIndex. Regardless of which I do it for, it's going to be tricky due to the fact that the ComboBox I'm trying to populate Value from is buried down in a data template, and that data template is not always used. I have two data templates (the other has no ComboBox), and the one to use is chosen by a DataTemplateSelector. I do not know how to get at the ComboBox (when it exists) programatically, hence my efforts to work in XAML. But I have a feeling I'm going to have to go in the direction you're suggesting and learn how to do this programatically.

Comment: I am not saying that you should do anything with the data template or the comboboxes. I am saying that you update the business object that your ui is bound to.  If you have a two-way binding, the ui will be updated to reflect this change. If you do databinding correctly, you should just be working with business objects, and never doing stuff like cmbCustomer.SelectedIndex=0;